# Is it possible to run a SOQL Query and get a Map returned?

Tags: apex, soql, map

It is possible to run query and the results inserted into an Apex list:

```
List<Opportunity> opportunities = [SELECT Opportunity.OwnerId,
                                          Opportunity.Probability,  
                                          Owner.Name FROM Opportunity 
                                    WHERE Opportunity.LastModifiedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:7];
```

Is it possible to return a Map? Where the key would be the OpportunityID and the value the Opportunity?

If not, what is the quickest way to convert to a map?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

I know only one:

```
Map<ID, Contact> m = new Map<ID, Contact>([SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact]);
```

Here is the doc: [Maps of sObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_map_sobject.htm)

Comment: That's a much better way to do it. I updated your link since it was just taking me to the home page instead of the specific topic.

Comment: This is one to commit to memory. I use it all the time.

Comment: Also, a quick way to get a set of returned Ids from a query is similar.. using the above code, just do Set<Id> myIds = m.keySet();

Comment: To clarify, this method can only be used to generate Maps using Id of the object you are querying as the key. If you want to use a different value as the key, you will have to iterate over the list returned by your query and put values into a Map. For instance, if you wanted to use AccountId as the key, you would need to do something like this: `List<Opportunity> oppList = [Select Id, AccountId from Opportunity];
Map<Id,Opportunity> accOppMap = new Map<Id,Opportunity>();
for(Opportunity o : oppList){
 accOppMap.put(o.AccountId,o);
}`

Comment: @mast0r link is again changed :)

Comment: any option to use it with child query like this.?

Map<AccountId, List<Contact>> m = new Map<AccountId, List<Contact>>([SELECT Id (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account]);

Comment: I was getting this result can you clarify why i'm getting isocurrecyfireld here
this is my Query-->
map<id,Account> acc = new map<id,account>([select id,name,CreatedDate from account limit 10]);
system.debug(acc);

result-->
0016F00002THXyjQAH=Account:{Id=0016F00002THXyjQAH, Name=test1, CreatedDate=2018-09-03 12:33:32, CurrencyIsoCode=USD}

Comment: The documentation suggests that something like this is possible: Map<String, Contact> m = new Map<String, Contact>([SELECT LastName, Email FROM Contact]) and it will execute, but the key of the map will be filled with the Id, and not the LastName, of the contact.

Answer (score 65):

Alternatively, if you have a list already -- say you're in a situation where you need a map, but aren't in a mood to refactor your entire class to handle a map, you can convert your list of results to a map thusly:

```
Map<Id,OBJ_TYPE> mapFromList = new Map<Id,OBJ_TYPE>(List_object_variable);
```

This will generate a map from the list as if you'd queried directly into a map.

Comment: that is a good tip.