# How to get record from id map

Tags: apex, trigger, map, salesforce-id, record

I have a before trigger to compare dates on entry. I want to get a recond based on an id from a map, How do I achieve this. Below is my example with my question on line

```
AAddress__c dummy = AccountAddress.get(aAN.id);
```

Apex

```
 public void OnBeforeInsert(List<AAddress__c> newAccountAddress){
    //EXECUTE BEFORE INSERT LOGIC
    date dateFilter = date.today().AddDays(- 5);

  Map<ID, AAddress__c> AccountAddress = new Map<ID, AAddress__c>([SELECT Id, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Account__c, Address_Type__c  FROM AAddress__c  WHERE Start_Date__c <= TODAY AND End_Date__c >= TODAY AND Status__c = true AND (LastModifiedDate >= :dateFilter OR LastModifiedDate = null)]);                           
      system.debug('AccountAddress: '+AccountAddress);                        

 for (AAddress__c aAN : newAccountAddress){
    AAddress__c dummy = AccountAddress.get(aAN.account__c);
     system.debug('dummy: '+dummy);
    if(aAN.Start_Date__c>= dummy.Start_Date__c && aAN.Start_Date__c <= dummy.End_Date__c ){
    aAN.addError('This startdate interferes with another adress');

    }
    if(aAN.End_Date__c>= dummy.Start_Date__c && aAN.End_Date__c <= dummy.End_Date__c ){
       aAN.addError( 'This enddate interferes with another adress');
    }
}                                                                   
}
```

Comment: I think your question is similar to this --> https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5288/is-it-possible-to-run-a-soql-query-and-get-a-map-returned

Comment: @RohitC I updated my code with you example but this gives me an empty ''Dummy'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in `trigger.newmap` to this method.
If you want old data then `trigger.oldmap`. By adding an extra parameter to your method. which will be 
`Map<Id,AAddress__c> mymap`.

Then you can get the record by id.

If you don't want to change the signature of the method then use below.

```
Map<Id, AAddress__c> mymap = new Map<Id,AAddress__c>(newAccountAddress);
//...
//...
AAddress__c dummy = mymap.get(aAN.id);
```