# Custom metadata to Map

Tags: map, developer

I have a custom metadata with 6 fields, I want to create a Map with two of those fields which are DeveloperName and NameAnimal__c, Is that possible to do that without a for loop?? Is there any standard method?

Comment: Will you query the metadata? Do you see it?https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5288/is-it-possible-to-run-a-soql-query-and-get-a-map-returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that converting a query directly to a Map is only possible if you are going to use a map of IDs and SObjects. In your case, I think I loop is the solution.